# Finding the height of the slope of a rollercoster loop-de-loop with friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, friction

I have the following diagram:

[image]

I am given all the listed parameters in the diagram, plus the mass of the pink body. The red track has a friction coefficient with the body equal to $\mu$, and the loop-de-loop itself is frictionless. I am tasked to calculate the minimal height, $h$ such that the pink body completes a full circle (in this case, I assume it means to pass the middle point of the loop-de-loop.

First, I know that when the body is located at the very bottom of the loop, its minimal velocity for it not to fall off at the very end equals $\sqrt {gr}$. At that point, the body has no potential gravitational energy, and thus has only kinetic energy. From this and from the energy conservation principle, I know that the following equation must hold true:

$$mgh - F_f\cdot d = \frac{mv^2}{2}$$

Where $F_f = mg\cos \alpha \cdot \mu$ is the friction applied on the body, and $d$ is the path of the hypotenuse, which equals to $\frac{h}{\sin \alpha}$.

I substitute:

$$mgh - \frac{mg\cos\alpha \cdot \mu\cdot h}{\sin \alpha} = \frac{mv^2}{2}$$
$$gh - \frac{g\cos \alpha \cdot \mu \cdot h}{\sin \alpha}=\frac{gr}{2}$$$$h - \cot\alpha \cdot \mu \cdot h = \frac{gr}{2}$$
$$2h(1-\cot \alpha\cdot \mu) = r$$
$$h = \frac{r}{2(1-\cot \alpha \cdot\mu)}$$

However, when I substitute the actual numbers for the parameters, I get a height which is less than the diameter of the loop-de-loop, which makes no sense, as intuitively the slope has to be higher to counteract the work done by the friction.

What's wrong?

Comment: "I know that when the body is located at the very bottom of the loop, its minimal velocity for it not to fall off at the very end equals $\sqrt{gr}$" - are you sure about that?

Comment: you missed a "g" in the fourth equation. In any case, the condition for full circle is not sqrt(gr), in such a case it will fall vertically once it reaches the top of the circle

Comment: the condition is that the normal force is zero at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sqrt {gR}$ is the speed at the top of the loop, not at the bottom. It is found by setting the centripetal force equal to the weight, $mg$, added to the reaction force, $N$, at the top. For the minimum speed, $N=0$.

$$\frac{mv^2}{R}=mg+N=mg$$
This gives $v=\sqrt{gR}$. To find the speed at the bottom of the loop, $u$, use conservation of energy.

$$\frac{1}{2}mu^2=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+2mgR$$
$$u^2=v^2+4gR=gR+4gR=5gR$$
This gives $u=\sqrt{5gR}$

Then apply the work-energy principle to find $h$ in terms of $u$ and $\alpha$.